# Magento242 - Virtual Host - CSS JS Not Loaded

Tags: magento2, migration

Current, We are using Magento242 With Virtual host, Somehow display the wrong path for CSS, js, and media file

Correct Path:  https://example.com/pub/static/frontend/Mgs/claue/en_US/mage/calendar.css

Wrong Path: https://example.com/static/frontend/Mgs/claue/en_US/mage/calendar.css

Pub folder does not include in CSS, JS URL

Please let me know if anyone has faced the same issue.

---

### Virtual Host

[image]

---

### Web Url

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your virtual site's conf file?

Comment: @RohanHapani, Update Virtual Host Setting

Comment: https://www.rohanhapani.com/solved-404-not-found-after-fresh-magento-2-4-2-installation/ Just make sure that all steps proper added.

Comment: @RohanHapani, Yes, its same

Answer (score 0):

@ravi dudhara - Dont keep /pub/ in the document root section at virtual host file. I am not sure what is the web server you are using.

If you are using nginx, please include the sample nginx config file in your virtual host file and ensure the url rewrite related nginx [ ngx_http_rewrite_module] modules are enabled.

In case if it is apache, it will automatically take the .htaccess file and do the necessary url rewrite. you need to make mod_rewrite module is enabled on the server.

Comment: We are using apache and mod_rewrite is enabled but still face the same error.

Comment: can you check whether you didnt miss anything from the mentioned configuration. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/apache.html#apache-help-rewrite

Comment: Thank you it's working.

Answer (score 0):

did you try with this code ??

i have remove pub/

sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.conf

Add lines :

ServerName example.local

ServerAlias [www.example.local](http://www.example.local)

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/pub

**Step 2**

sudo a2ensite example.conf

sudo systemctl reload apache2

sudo gedit /etc/hosts

sudo service apache2 restart

**step 3**

insert the code in Database

insert core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) values (null, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);

Comment: Yes I had tried the same but its not work.

Comment: @RaviDudhara please go this location pub/static and  check .htaccess (hidden file). if this file not exist, you can copy same file another project and past it. and then run all comamnds again.

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php biin/magento cache:flush